# Recover a USB flash driver reporting 0 bytes

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I'm not sure it's the right section to be asking this question, sorry if it's not.

Last night I used [openSUSE ImageWriter](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick) to create a USB bootable flash driver, however the drive is completely unusable at the moment, it reports 0b.

I tried cfdisk, fdisk, parted and I even tried
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024 count=100` and I ended up with dd exiting with 0b written and an error message No space left on device.

It seems that the USB pen has lost track of it's storage, is there any way to fix it? or should I just throw it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `fdisk` and recreate its partitions. I have seen usb flash drivers miraculously being fixed after being formated by Windows, so you may want to try that too.

Comment: The problem is that I tried fdisk, but it reports no media found and exits.. It's like the USB flash driver has no media at all, worse it's recognised as Generic USB drive instead of PTY...